# Why does floor(Infinity) give large integer with opposite sign?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following Fortran program:

```fortran
program test
double precision :: inf, one, zero
one = 1.d0
zero = 0.d0
inf = one/zero
write(6,*) floor( inf)
write(6,*) floor(-inf)
end program test
```

compiled with `gfortran test.f95` prints this:

```
-2147483648
 2147483647
```

I understand why these values, they are the maximum (or minimum) values of a 4-byte integer, which is the default in gfortran, and `floor` returns an integer.

What I don't get is their sign... Mathematically, a number line would be:

```
-Infinity    -2147483648    0    2147483647    Infinity
--------------------------------------------------------->
```

But apparently my program sees it the other way around. *Mathematically* speaking, `floor(inf)` should return (after type conversion) `2147483647` and `floor(-inf)` should return `-2147483648`.

What causes the change of sign? What convention does gfortran use to make this odd result?  Is there a convention in Fortran more generally?

Furthermore, other functions that do type conversion return strange (for me, at least) values:

```fortran
write(6,*) floor( inf), nint( inf), ceiling( inf)
write(6,*) floor(-inf), nint(-inf), ceiling(-inf)
```

prints:

```
-2147483648    0   -2147483647
 2147483647    0   -2147483648
```

---

#### Update:

After agentp's comment I found out that this doesn't happen to infinities only. Any large number (larger than `2^32`) will give the same results.

And to make things even stranger, this program:

```
program test
real :: big
big = 2.d0**32-1000
print*, big
write(6,*) floor( big), nint( big), ceiling( big)
write(6,*) floor(-big), nint(-big), ceiling(-big)
end program test
```

returns this quite bizarre result:

```
-2147483648       -1024 -2147483647
 2147483647        1024 -2147483648
```

---

Just out of curiosity I checked and this C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
   float one = 1;
   float zero = 0;
   float inf = one/zero;
   int iflr = floor(inf);
   int irnd = round(inf);
   int icei = ceil(inf);
   printf("%d - %d - %d\n",iflr,irnd,icei);
   iflr = floor(-inf);
   irnd = round(-inf);
   icei = ceil(-inf);
   printf("%d - %d - %d\n",iflr,irnd,icei);
}
```

compiled with `gcc test.c -lm` and it prints `-2147483648` for all cases.

Comment: One could say that Fortran doesn't have a convention for this answer, so would you want to ask about gfortran in particular?  [Also, 4-byte integers certainly aren't the default in Fortran.]

Comment: I don't have other Fortran compilers than gfortran, so yes, a gfortran answer is perfect :). Should I edit the question adding this? [I thought that they were, since I didn't use any compiler flag say otherwise... What is the default, then?]

Comment: I've put a "gfortran" limiting thing in there, but hopefully leaving it open for someone who can contradict my first statement.

Comment: see what you get for real values greater than 2^31

Comment: I meant to say: I removed the [tag:ieee-754] tag because you aren't working purely with IEEE-compliant floating point (converting to integer).  If you use `ieee_rint()`, etc., you may be more comfortable in the outcome.

Comment: @agentp Good suggestion... The results are the same! This drops my hypothesis that it was something to do with the infinities.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the corrections :) I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @francescalus See my update above...

Comment: Unless you have engaged IEEE arithmetic by setting a compiler option (which doesn't appear to be the case from the question) then I think division by 0 results in undefined behaviour (not that the term is used in the Fortran standard) so a compiler is pretty much free to do what it wants from that point on.  Fortran arithmetic is, by the standard, not quite the same as IEEE arithmetic and I'm not aware that any of the widely used Fortran compilers engages it (IEEE arithmetic) by default.

Comment: I believe OP is incorrect and that *Mathematically speaking* `floor(1.0/0.0)` is not defined.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The division by 0 is returning infinity and I thought that (probably should change "mathematically" to "numerically") rounding it *down* should return the maximum possible value, that in this case would be the largest 32-bit integer. But the minimum integer makes no sense for me... I didn't know that about the IEEE arithmetic though...

Comment: note `int(large real)` also returns -2147483648. The mathematically correct result simply can't be represented, so I don't see a point in arguing what the "correct" thing is to return.

Comment: @agentp But it would make a lot more sense if `int(large real)` returned `large integer` instead of `small integer`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why? Neither result is correct. If the result of the operation can't be represented in the return value all bets are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematically* floor(inf) and floor(-inf) should return inf and -inf because changing an infinite number by a scalar is still infinite.

Interestingly, iFort prints

```
 -2147483648
 -2147483648
```

as opposed to what the gfortran results were.

Additionally, your second test program compiled with iFort prints:

```
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648
-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648
```

The real issue here is that floor() specifically returns an integer and there are no *denormalized* integers and certainly no special bit patterns that can store values such as inf or NAN in an integer. With no such specifications, its programmer beware.

Comment: Indeed, mathematically floor(Inf) should return Inf. But in my imagination, since there aren't Infinite in integers (in Fortran, at least), I thought that the result should be the closest value possible, *i.e.* `2147483647` (and the inverse for the negative Infinity). But if iFort returns different values then it's implementation dependent... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Another thing, just out of curiosity: Can you please add the result to the program I present in the update to my question, please? I find that result quite strange...

Comment: I meant for you to put the result of iFort in your answer :). Well, this shows that neither compiler has the result I expected for floor(Inf), but at least iFort is consistent with its results :P

Comment: in ifort 18.0 debug mode, the code will not even compile.